# What are these textures?

Tags: texturing

I downloaded a model recently, and it came with the following textures:

[image]

The first image is the diffuse (d) texture and the middle one in the second row is the normals (n) textures, and I know what to do with those, but what are the ones marked (g), (m), and (z)?

Comment: I don't know about the g and m, but the z PROBABLY is a displacement map. Please tell us where you got the model from. We might (or might not) be able to help after that.

Comment: This model is from the game Watcher of Realms, a Unity game.

Comment: The other textures do not look like anything particular in my knowledge, so it could be other textures packed into one. See [ChannelPacking - polycount](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/ChannelPacking)

Comment: *"I downloaded a model recently, and it came with the following textures"* - aren't the textures actually used by the model?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, but I'm using it in Blender, so I am trying to figure out how to apply them there.